A lightning-datatable with the rows and columns transposed?
A lightning-datatable has columns that can have varying data types so a column can represent a record field and a row an individual record. I have a need for the opposite: a column per record and a row per record field of varying type. I also need the cells to be editable, though minimal other features.
Before I create my own component, is such a component available anywhere (implemented in LWC)? Or other ideas?
Interesting that this is possible just using CSS where you have full control of the CSS.

Would it be possible to show in a diagram format what do you want the lightning table to look like. Is it the same way as showed in the codepen example?

Hi @NagendraSingh, Field labels in the first column, then each column after showing the corresponding fields from the records.

After a few hours I've a proof of concept LWC coded from scratch but using the Data Tables SLDS classes so the output looks reasonable inclduing for cell editing. I only need to support four types of fields so four permutations of lightning-input and lightning-formatted-* to handle those and don't need much beyond that.
But would still prefer a ready made solution if one exists.
